# com.segment.analytics.android:analytics error while submitting my app to Google Play Console

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-analytics, expo

I am trying to submit my React Native EXPO app to Google Play Store for approval, but I am getting this error:

SDK Segment Analytics Android (com.segment.analytics.android:analytics), 4.9.4 collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the user data policy.

You can't publish this release due to this policy issue. To be allowed to publish, you may consider moving to another SDK; removing this SDK; or if available from your SDK provider, upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code.

According to the information provided by your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading to 4.10.1. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.

I am new to React Native. Please Help.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17845 I hope this is helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

Just happened to me too, possibly it will be solved if we try to generate the bundle using the EAS command.

Then change this command:

```
expo build:android
```

by this command:

```
eas build -p android
```

Then the bundle will be cleaner because it will bring only what it needs. Another alternative might be to update the version of one of the possible packages involved such as "expo-firebase-analytics" or "expo-ads-admob". In my case I currently have:

```
"expo-ads-admob":"~12.0.0", "firebase": "8.2.3", "expo-firebase-analytics":"~6.0.0".
```

I have not updated it yet

pd: remember that in future versions of expo I understand that the command will stop working:

```
expo build:android
```

Comment: Did this work? I used `eas build` but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with expo-analytics-segment.

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/0d1f072871c9a9f76ca622d3fe5cb48a4bd832d2/packages/expo-analytics-segment/android/build.gradle#L87

```
api 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.9.4'
```

But this is only removed if you use EAS.

Comment: I don't use expo-analytics-segment & I already use `EAS build` but the problem still persists. Can it be because of other issues?

Answer (score 1):

Expo uses device IDs in their analytics framework so **you must select that your app collects `Device or other IDs` in the Data Safety section** in the Google play console when submitting.

According to [this post](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1320#issuecomment-360320090):

> - We collect anonymous usage statistics through Amplitude which aren't specific to your app and help us figure out how people are using Expo, as covered [here](https://expo.dev/privacy).
> - By default there is no data being sent to Segment at all, unless you use the Segment API in your app for your own purposes.
>
> Even though no Segment calls are made by default, since the code is statically present in your binary that could run Segment, you still need to check the IDFA boxes listed in our [guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/app-stores.html#ios-specific-guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in `expo-analytics-segment` 11.2.1 - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17845. You can update with:

```
expo install expo-analytics-segment
```