# EAS build failed with error code 1 but Expo Build succeeds, i need EAS build to remove unused packages like com.segment.analytics.android:analytics

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console

yesterday, I have published my App build using Expo build:android on google play console but receive the error message:

SDK Segment Analytics Android (com.segment.analytics.android:analytics), 4.9.4 collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

You can't publish this release due to this policy issue. To be allowed to publish, you may consider moving to another SDK; removing this SDK; or if available from your SDK provider, upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code.

According to the information provided by your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading to 4.10.1. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

ACTION REQUIRED: Upload a new compliant version AND deactivate the noncompliant version.

Read through the User Data policy for more details, and how to submit an updated app for review here.

I tried to find this package in App.json to remove it but it is not present their.
I have also checked the node modules but can't find their too. So, the only way to remove this package is by using EAS Build as it removes the unused packages but the build fails with non zero error code.
So, i am unable to figure out the reason of the build failing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.segment.analytics.android:analytics error while submitting my app to Google Play Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584447/com-segment-analytics-androidanalytics-error-while-submitting-my-app-to-google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved now!
I want to share how i solved the issue:
I checked the build logs in EAS build, what is find their in the prebuild logs that their are some errors and warnings.
So,

> i started by resolving these logs errors like sound.wav file not found
> that i have mentioned in APP.json for notifications.

I found that i have not given the **file path correctly in App.json file** that causes this issue.
After fixing this I was able to do EAS build successfully!

*For those who are getting this warning/error in Google Play Console: SDK Segment Analytics Android (com.segment.analytics.android:analytics), 4.9.4 collects personal or sensitive data ...*

**Please do EAS build if you was doing Expo build. This Error will be solved by doing EAS build as it removes the unused packages and you are good to go to publish the app on Google play console without any errors**.